# NullPointerException for org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

Facing `NullPointerException` for `WorkbenchPage.ShowView(String viewId)`.

stackstrace is as following.

!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setState(WorkbenchPage.java:4024)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.toggleZoom(WorkbenchPage.java:4096)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchIntroManager.setIntroStandby(WorkbenchIntroManager.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.checkIntro(WorkbenchPage.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyShowView(WorkbenchPage.java:1170)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyShowView(WorkbenchPage.java:1140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$20.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3925)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:3922)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:3898)
    at com.rcp.app.foundation.ui.services.PerspectiveChangeListener.perspectiveActivated(PerspectiveChangeListener.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList$1.run(PerspectiveListenerList.java:74)
```

I not getting what I am missing exactly. Can anyone help me to find out what exactly I am missing in this flow.

I wrote perspectiveChangeListner as following.

```
    public class PerspectiveChangeListener implements IPerspectiveListener, IPerspectiveListener3
{
/**
  * WindowTitleUpdater Object to update the window title based on selected erspectives.
  */
    private WindowTitleUpdater windowTitleUpdater = null;



/**
     * Constructor.
     * @param windowTitleUpdater
     */
    public PerspectiveChangeListener( WindowTitleUpdater windowTitleUpdater )
    {
        this.windowTitleUpdater = windowTitleUpdater;
    }

   /**
     * (non-Javadoc).
     * @see org.eclipse.ui.IPerspectiveListener#perspectiveActivated(org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage,
     *      org.eclipse.ui.IPerspectiveDescriptor)
     */


 @Override
    public void perspectiveActivated( IWorkbenchPage page, IPerspectiveDescriptor perspective )
    {
        windowTitleUpdater.updateTitle( false );
        if ( perspective.getId().equals( "com.app.perspective.id" ) )
        {
            try
            {
                page.showView( "com.app.view.id" );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this your code doing the show view? If so show us the code.

Comment: @greg-449 updated the question to for code please check

Comment: I don't see any particular problem. Possibly something does not like a view being shown in this listener. You could try using `Display.asyncExec` to run the `showView` when the UI becomes idle.

Comment: @greg-449 it worked for me. But didn't get the reason behind the issue.

Comment: Added an answer with some more details of what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `perspectiveActivated` listener is fired by the `WorkbenchPage`, the page seems not expect the listener to call the page `showView` method in the listener and gets confused if it does.

Use `Display.asyncExec` to run the `showView` call. This will run the code after the WorkbenchPage has finished the work it is doing.